# Cancel a pending shutdown with /sbin/shutdown -c does not work

Tags: systemd, reboot

I have planned a reboot with `/sbin/shutdown -r 23:30`. But when I try to cancel it with `/sbin/shutdown -c`, I am not sure if it is really cancelled.

Because a `cat /run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled`still shows

```
USEC=1581460200000000
WARN_WALL=1
MODE=reboot
```

But a `busctl get-property org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager ScheduledShutdown` (the [systemd-logind API](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/)) shows

```
(st) "" 0
```

So, whom to believe?

My system is Debian 9.12

Comment: I know very little about this, so I may be completely wrong, but are you sure the freedesktop stuff is relevant? Don't those work through a separate interface? In any case, have you checked if the values change there? I mean, check before `shutdown -r`, check after, and then check after `shutdown -c`. What changes? Also, what actually happens? Does the system shutdown at the specified time, or is the shutdown cancelled?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it turned out that the info in `/run/systemd/shutdown/scheduled`is not very accurate and not updated if a shutdown is cancelled. The above mentioned shutdown did not occur. The only valid solution to check for a planned shutdown seems to be

```
busctl get-property org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager ScheduledShutdown
```

which shows for example

```
(st) "" 0
```

if there is no planned shutdown, and

```
(st) "reboot" 1581546600000000
```

if there is a shutdown with reboot planned at the specified time (epoch in microseconds).